# How does this NSTimer Pause / Resume work?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I'm using the following code I found to pause and unpause an `NSTimer`. I hate not knowing how code works, so I'm hoping someone can give me a brief explanation of what's happening here. What's the significance of the two `NSDate` objects used in the `pause` method? What's the significance of the `-1` in the `resume` method? Thanks in advance!

```
- (void) pause
{
    pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0];
    previousFireDate = [self fireDate];
    [self setFireDate: [NSDate distantFuture]];
}

- (void) resume
{
    // 
    float pauseTime = -1 * [pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
    [self setFireDate: [previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval: pauseTime sinceDate: previousFireDate]];
}
```

Comment: That resume code should not be using the init method on a date that has already been initialised.  Use `-dateByAddingTimeInterval:` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume that your timer would fire today at 11:00.
(For simplicity, I use only HH:MM for dates in the comments.)

At 09:00 the `pause` action is executed:

```
// pauseStart = current date/time ("now") = 09:00:
pauseStart = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0];
// previousFireDate = 11:00:
previousFireDate = [self fireDate];
// set new fireDate to something far far away to prevent timer from firing:
[self setFireDate: [NSDate distantFuture]];
```

At 09:10 the `resume` action is executed:

```
// pauseTime = difference between "pause" and "resume" (now) = 10 minutes:
float pauseTime = -1 * [pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
// set new fireDate = previous fireDate + pauseTime = 11:10:
[self setFireDate: [previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval: pauseTime sinceDate: previousFireDate]];
```

The factor (-1) is required because `pauseStart` is earlier than "now".

So `pause` "pauses" the timer by setting the fire date to a distant date in the future (Jan 1st, 4001).

`resume` restores the fire date to the old fire date plus the time interval that elapsed
between "pause" and "resume".

*Remark:* As @JeremyP noticed in his comment,

```
[self setFireDate: [previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval: pauseTime sinceDate: previousFireDate]];
```

is not correct, because it sends an init message to the already initialized object `previousFireDate`. Correct (and even shorter) is:

```
[self setFireDate:[previousFireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:pauseTime]];
```

Comment: I'll  give you +1 if you fix the line that sends an init method to an already initialised `NSDate`

Comment: @JeremyP: Shame on me for not noticing that!